# Make LaTeX left-aligned in css like everthing else when exporting from org-mode

Tags: css, org-mode, mathjax

I would like to left-align the `LaTeX` equation when exporting from `org-mode` using `org-html-export-to-html`, as it looks a tad out-of-place in the setup below.

[image: LaTeX in the Middle]

In case the stylesheet itself is required: https://github.com/shadowrylander/settings/blob/main/src/styles/primary/syvl.css

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to give a minimal, reproducible example here.

Answer (score 1):

From [13.9.10 Math formatting in HTML export](https://orgmode.org/manual/Math-formatting-in-HTML-export.html):

```
#+HTML_MATHJAX: align: left
```

Found when analyzing the *top* half of the html file and finding the following:

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        displayAlign: "left",
        displayIndent: "0em",

        "HTML-CSS": { scale: 100,
                        linebreaks: { automatic: "false" },
                        webFont: "TeX"
                       },
        SVG: {scale: 100,
              linebreaks: { automatic: "false" },
              font: "TeX"},
        NativeMML: {scale: 100},
        TeX: { equationNumbers: {autoNumber: "AMS"},
               MultLineWidth: "85%",
               TagSide: "right",
               TagIndent: ".8em"
             }
});
</script>
```